# Fatal error related to fabric.io in Android app after migration to Firebase crashlytics

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, crash-dumps, crashlytics-android

I used fabric.io crashlytics in my Android app.

Recently, fabric.io has been deceased and it was recommended to migrate to Firebase. I followed the migration steps in the console and the app successfully migrated to Firebase (I see the crash logs). The mobile SDK was however not changed.

Firebase now warns that the fabric.io SDK is deprecated and will stop working after 15th November, 2020.

I followed the steps required for migration

https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=android

and removed all stuff related to fabric.io from my application.

**After that, my app begins to crash at startup!** Here's the stack trace.

```
07-23 13:02:18.337  2965  2965 E CrashlyticsCore: .
07-23 13:02:18.338  2965  2965 E CrashlyticsCore: .     |  |
07-23 13:02:18.338  2965  2965 E CrashlyticsCore: .     |  |
07-23 13:02:18.338  2965  2965 E CrashlyticsCore: .     |  |
07-23 13:02:18.338  2965  2965 E CrashlyticsCore: .   \ |  | /
07-23 13:02:18.338  2965  2965 E CrashlyticsCore: .    \    /
07-23 13:02:18.338  2965  2965 E CrashlyticsCore: .     \  /
07-23 13:02:18.338  2965  2965 E CrashlyticsCore: .      \/
07-23 13:02:18.338  2965  2965 E CrashlyticsCore: .
07-23 13:02:18.338  2965  2965 E CrashlyticsCore: This app relies on Crashlytics. Please sign up for access at https://fabric.io/sign_up,
07-23 13:02:18.338  2965  2965 E CrashlyticsCore: install an Android build tool and ask a team member to invite you to this app's organization.
07-23 13:02:18.338  2965  2965 E CrashlyticsCore: .
07-23 13:02:18.338  2965  2965 E CrashlyticsCore: .      /\
07-23 13:02:18.338  2965  2965 E CrashlyticsCore: .     /  \
07-23 13:02:18.338  2965  2965 E CrashlyticsCore: .    /    \
07-23 13:02:18.338  2965  2965 E CrashlyticsCore: .   / |  | \
07-23 13:02:18.338  2965  2965 E CrashlyticsCore: .     |  |
07-23 13:02:18.338  2965  2965 I chatty  : uid=10201(com.hmdm.launcher) identical 1 line
07-23 13:02:18.338  2965  2965 E CrashlyticsCore: .     |  |
07-23 13:02:18.338  2965  2965 E CrashlyticsCore: .
07-23 13:02:18.339  2965  2965 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
07-23 13:02:18.340   893  3596 I CameraService: UidPolicy: onUidActive, uid = 10201
07-23 13:02:18.340   893  3596 I CameraService: onUidStateChanged: uid=10201, procState=2
07-23 13:02:18.340  1381  1428 D GameManagerService: noteResumeComponent(), resumeComponent: com.hmdm.launcher
07-23 13:02:18.341  2965  2965 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-23 13:02:18.341  2965  2965 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.hmdm.launcher, PID: 2965
07-23 13:02:18.341  2965  2965 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsInitProvider: io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.UnmetDependencyException: This app relies on Crashlytics. Please sign up for access at https://fabric.io/sign_up,
07-23 13:02:18.341  2965  2965 E AndroidRuntime: install an Android build tool and ask a team member to invite you to this app's organization.
07-23 13:02:18.341  2965  2965 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7413)
07-23 13:02:18.341  2965  2965 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6953)
07-23 13:02:18.341  2965  2965 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6844)
07-23 13:02:18.341  2965  2965 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:268)
07-23 13:02:18.341  2965  2965 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1982)
07-23 13:02:18.341  2965  2965 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
07-23 13:02:18.341  2965  2965 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
07-23 13:02:18.341  2965  2965 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7814)
07-23 13:02:18.341  2965  2965 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-23 13:02:18.341  2965  2965 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
07-23 13:02:18.341  2965  2965 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1047)
07-23 13:02:18.341  2965  2965 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.UnmetDependencyException: This app relies on Crashlytics. Please sign up for access at https://fabric.io/sign_up,
07-23 13:02:18.341  2965  2965 E AndroidRuntime: install an Android build tool and ask a team member to invite you to this app's organization.
07-23 13:02:18.341  2965  2965 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsCore.onPreExecute(CrashlyticsCore.java:233)
07-23 13:02:18.341  2965  2965 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsCore.onPreExecute(CrashlyticsCore.java:207)
07-23 13:02:18.341  2965  2965 E AndroidRuntime:        at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.onPreExecute(InitializationTask.java:44)
07-23 13:02:18.341  2965  2965 E AndroidRuntime:        at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:611)
07-23 13:02:18.341  2965  2965 E AndroidRuntime:        at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.PriorityAsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(PriorityAsyncTask.java:43)
07-23 13:02:18.341  2965  2965 E AndroidRuntime:        at io.fabric.sdk.android.Kit.initialize(Kit.java:69)
07-23 13:02:18.341  2965  2965 E AndroidRuntime:        at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.initializeKits(Fabric.java:440)
07-23 13:02:18.341  2965  2965 E AndroidRuntime:        at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.init(Fabric.java:384)
07-23 13:02:18.341  2965  2965 E AndroidRuntime:        at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.setFabric(Fabric.java:342)
07-23 13:02:18.341  2965  2965 E AndroidRuntime:        at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.with(Fabric.java:313)
07-23 13:02:18.341  2965  2965 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsInitProvider.onCreate(CrashlyticsInitProvider.java:27)
07-23 13:02:18.341  2965  2965 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2113)
07-23 13:02:18.341  2965  2965 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2087)
07-23 13:02:18.341  2965  2965 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7408)
07-23 13:02:18.341  2965  2965 E AndroidRuntime:        ... 10 more
```

I returned back all dependencies to fabric.io in build.gradle - and the error disappeared.

Looks like Firebase Crashlytics internally uses fabric.io in its code and **requires** references to the deprecated fabric.io code, which is not mentioned in the Firebase help article.

Or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: You should follow this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?platform=android

Comment: Thank you for the link! Looks like I missed this step: Remove the Fabric Crashlytics SDK. Will try again and write about the result!

Comment: After following the migration instructions, I was able to avoid this issue and get a crash report. But I got another weird issue - Crashlytics crashes if I'm doing an incremental build of my app: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63089606/